# Horizontal or Vertical Scrolling But Not Both

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, horizontalscrollview, vertical-scrolling

Is there a way to create a custom view with vertical or horizontal scrolling but not both?
When in portrait mode, vertical scrolling should be enabled and horizontal scrolling should be disabled
When in landscape mode, horizontal scrolling is enabled and vertical scrolling is disabled.

Comment: Just update the `contentSize` property correctly on orientation change event and it should work automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the contentSize property of your UIScrollView depending on which orientation you are going to turn to.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation) {
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, scrollViewContentHeight)];
    } else {
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollViewContentWidth, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height)];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. i'm going to try this solution tomorrow. Another question, is it possible to not show the scrollbar image?

Comment: It is possible, just set showsHorizontalScrollIndicator or showsVerticalScrollIndicator to NO.

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on your UIScrollView's content size. If the content size overflows the scrollView's frame's height - you'll enable horizontal scrolling. If it exceeds the height, you'll enable vertical scrolling.